# ChilKat: How do you convert CkByteData to CkString

Tags: chilkat

Does anyone know how to convert a CkByteData object to a CkString object?

I have a CkByteData object full of either UTF-8 string data or raw bytes which I want to convert to a CkString object.

I don't mind if the data goes all gobbledygook (the code page translation is incorrect) in the CkString, as I will be searching the CkString for very a specific string, and goggledygook won't match correctly.

I could search the bytes for what I want, but as it is a complex text search so I would prefer to use the CkString functions.

I am sure there is a neat and tidy why to do this with ChilKat which I cannot see.
Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "appendN" member function of CkString to add the bytes to the CkString.
HOWEVER you are adding bytes to a string without a code page (which is normally bad) and there is a cast involved (again normally bad).

```
CkString ckString; 
ckString.appendN((char *)ckByteData.getData(), ckByteData.getSize());
```

This solution works for my requirements.